# cameraOverlayView in ios7 hides default camera toolbar, but works in ios6

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

My code to place an overlay in the imagepicker works in iOS6, but not in ios7. In iOS6 the camera display fine; it appears that the overlay is slotted between the picker and the controls nicely. In iOS7, it seems that the overlay is placed on the very top layer, hiding the controls. I can still click on the take photo button though.

Is there anyway to put the camera controls back on top? Or is this a bug?

```
imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageString]];
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
imagePicker.delegate=self;
imagePicker.title=@"Test";
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES ];
[imagePicker release];
```